# How to bind a DOM element to a custom $.touchpress event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a custom event called `touchpress` that an object can be bound to using the usual JQuery `.bind()`.

Here is how I currently work out a touchpress for a button:

```
$("#myButton").bind("touchstart", function() {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
}).touchend(function() {
    var duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
});
```

But I want to be able to bind any element to this event and simply trigger a touchpress event

```
$("#myButton").bind("touchpress", onTouchPress);
```

I tried to use a trigger:

```
$(document).trigger("touchpress", duration);
```

but didn't know what to bind it to.  I also didn't know what to bind the touchstart event to....  Anyone want to help me glue these pieces together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `touchpress` wrapper:

```
$.fn.touchpress = function(fn){
  var startTime;
  return this.on({
    "touchpress": fn,
    "touchstart": function(){
      startTime = new Date().getTime();
    },
    "touchend": function(){
      var duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
      $(this).trigger("touchpress", duration);
    }
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$("span").touchpress(function(evt, duration){
  console.log(duration);
});
```

​

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to get at! Out of curiosity is it possible to then do $("span").bind("touchpress", function(duration){});  As with other events such as click?

Comment: @CrimsonChin, No, you need to use the wrapper. I updated the version to something that might look a bit better

Answer (score 0):

javascript is case sensitive.

you bind a `touchPress` event but then trigger a `touchpress`. These are not the same event.

Answer (score 0):

Event bubbling goes up the dom tree.

So you if you attach a handler to "myButton" you need to trigger the event either directly on the element or on a child of that element.

**Binding**: attaching a function that will fire when the event reaches the element that has that function bound to that event

**Triggering**: firing the event from a source element up its dom hierarchy until a top element is reached or a handler calls event.stopPropagation();

Example:

dom structure:

```
document->body->div->button[id=myButton]
```

you can bind any event on any of the elements in the dom

event bubbling if fired from button[id=myButton]

```
button[id=myButton]->div->body->document
```

In your case:

```
$("#myButton").trigger("touchpress"); //this triggers the handler that will respond to touchpress
```

If you don't/want know the source of element that you need to trigger the event from you could add a marker class you those elements and trigger the event on each of them manually

```
$('.has-touchpress-handler').trigger('touchpress');
```

Comment: Ok.   I but what I'm getting at is I don't want to bind #myButton to the touchstart event I just want to wrap all that up as an event and be able to just bind myButton to the touchpress event.  If that's any clearer?

Comment: @Alexander: ha, ok.  Lets say I have six buttons, I want to bind them all to the touchpress event.  the touchpress has to be calculated for each button.  So instead of binding them all to the touchstart event I wanted to create a new event called touchpress. any better?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="main_content"></<div>
```

JS Code:

```
document.getElementById('main_content').ontouchstart=onStartFunction;
/* or for multiple elements using jquery*/
$('.myBtns').each(function(){
   this.ontouchstart=onStartFunction;
});

function onStartFunction(e){

      //e.stopPropagation(); // if necessary

      // your code goes here

}
```

you can bind every event you like ontouchstart, ontouchmove, ontouchend etc.
if you use e.stopPropagation() this will prevent the event to bubble